# dynamically determine type of Option when it has value 'None'

Tags: f#, option-type

There is some difficulty in getting Option type dynamically. Suppose I have a function:

```
let printType x =
   if (box x) = null then printfn "the type is 'null'"
   else printfn "the type is %A" (x.GetType())
```

And we have the output here:

```
printType 3          // the type is System.Int32
printType (Some(3))  // the type is Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[System.Int32]
printType None       // the type is null
printType null       // the type is null
```

How to differentiate between None and null when getting an expression's type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** *The code quotation is not needed and typeof can be used instead, see @Tomas Petricek's answer*

You could use a code quotation to get the type from None

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let printType x = 
    let typeOfX = <@ x @>.Type

    if not <| FSharpType.IsUnion(typeOfX) && (box x) = null then 
        printfn "the type is 'null'"
    else 
        printfn "the type is %A" typeOfX
```

Your input:

```
printType 3          // the type is System.Int32
printType (Some(3))  // the type is Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[System.Int32]
printType None       // the type is Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[System.Object]
printType null       // the type is 'null'
```

Comment: I think this is just a more complicated (and slower) way of getting the static type (as in my answer). If you call it with boxed `None` value, then you get "null" rather than the runtime type (because the runtime type is lost). Try `printType (box (None : int option))` - you'd expect to get "runtime type" `int option`, but your code prints "null" (similarly to my answer).

Comment: Yours will be faster, but doesn't get the whole type of union case so depends on what he needs I guess. Imo I'd expect it to print that it's null since boxing `None` returns a null `System.Object`

Comment: Mine version statically restricts the argument to be an option - so it can only be called with options as arguments. But my point is that there is no reason for using `<@ x @>.Type`, because it returns the same as `typeof<'T>` (where `'T` is the static type of `x`).

Comment: @ Tomas Petricek. There is no need in restriction argument type to Option type. It can be of any type.

Comment: @TomasPetricek if it's restricted to the option type @Oleg won't be able to call `printType 3` as he does in his sample, to be able to do that I needed to use `<@ x @>.Type`

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh If you do not want to restrict the argument to option, you can just change `(x:'T option)` to `(x:'T)` and then get the static type via `typeof<'T>`. There is *really* no reason why you would need quotations here. I added the solution (based on your code) to my answer.

Comment: Aside - I gave you +1 because you are solving Oleg's question better than my answer did (and I had to steal that part from you :-)). I'm just trying to point out that using quotation will only give you the static type of `x` (which can be done more easily using `typeof<_>`)

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean now that definitely is better, thanks

Answer (score 7):

At runtime, option `None` values are represented as `null` and so you cannot determine their runtime type. However, you could write a generic function that prints the static type of the option:

```
let printType (x:'T option) =
  printfn "Static type is: %s" (typeof<'T>.Name)
```

Depending on what you need, this might or might not do what you need.

```
printType (None : int option)     // Int32
printType (None : string option)  // String 
printType None                    // Object (the default used by the inference)
```

**EDIT** If you want to be able to call the function on any arguments, you can use  `typeof<'T>` as in my example together with the rest of the logic as in the solution by Matthew. The following does the same thing as Matthew's snippet (but it does not create quotations for no good reason):

```
let printType (x:'T) =
  let typeOfX = typeof<'T>
  if not <| FSharpType.IsUnion(typeOfX) && (box x) = null then 
    printfn "Static type is %s, but the value is 'null'" typeOfX.Name
  else 
    printfn "Static type is %s and value is not 'null'" typeOfX.Name
```

Comment: To be pedantically correct, we'd yet need to test against the unit type, as per [§5.4.8 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf) _Types with null as a representation value._

Comment: I believe the `not` in the condition is there by mistake, `Option` is a union, isn't it? Also, there is an alternative way to check whether we're dealing with `Option`: `let isOption = typedefof<'T> = typedefof<Option<obj>>`

Answer (score 0):

This can be a common problem when implementing interpreters. To add to the above solutions, you could also do the following:

```
open System

type TagObj (obj : obj, t : Type) =
    member __.Obj = obj
    member __.Type = t

and TagObj<'T>(value : 'T) =
    inherit TagObj(value, typeof<'T>)

    member __.Value = value
    override __.ToString() = sprintf "%O" value

let mkTag x = TagObj<_>(x) :> TagObj

// examples

let t = mkTag (None : int option)
let t' = mkTag ()

t.Obj = t'.Obj // true
t.Type = t'.Type // false
```

This is roughly how constant values are represented in quotations as well.